# Define: A solution of a linear equations system + Row, Column & Null spaces relations

Tags: linear-algebra

The linear equations system:
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\1 & 2 & 3 & 6 \\1 & 3 & 5 & 9\end{array}\right).$$
Has the following solution:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
z \\
3 - 2z \\
z
\end{pmatrix} ,z \in \mathbb{R}$$
In an attempt to understand better a matrix properties:

1. How does that solution relate to the matrix, in regards with its column and row space?
2. In general - Do the row, column & null spaces have some relation and what that is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the solution space as the set
$$\{\pmatrix{0\\3\\0} + z \pmatrix{1\\-2\\1}, z\in\mathbb R\}$$
This tells you that

1. $A\pmatrix{0\\3\\0} = \pmatrix{3\\6\\9}$
2. $A\pmatrix{1\\-2\\1} = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0}$, i.e. $(1,-2,1)^T\in\ker A$
3. $\ker A$ (the null space) is spanned by $\pmatrix{1\\-2\\1}$ because the solution space has dimension 1.

If you find two linearly independent vectors orthogonal to $(1,-2,1)^T$, such as $(1,0,-1)^T$ and $(2,1,0)^T$, these span the image of $A$. Since $A=A^T$ is symmetric, they also span the image of $A^T$.